# choosing energy instead of hp count in aodv

Tags: c++, ns2

I am modifying AODV protocol of NS2 to change the criterion of route selection. I have changed the condition into energy residue in the aodv code for receiving packets and reply. Can anyone explain 'precursor' related code's purpose. Should I modify that part also? Is there any other work similar to what I am doing?

Answer (score 0):

if u want to choose the path based on energy level means first you have to add new field energy in routing protocol .without that field how the nodes can check the energy levels of its won with the neighbouring nodes..

first try to add energy field in aodv/packet.h